# Access share files from Windows Server 2012 IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have an MVC4 application with Windows authentication. After I publish IIS 7 in Windows Server 2008, I enable ASP.NET impersonation. In the application I need read files from another server's shared folder.

Everything works fine. However, when I publish to IIS in Windows Server 2012, if I open the app with http://localhost/app it works. If I open it with http://server2012/app, I am not allowed to access the files from shared folder. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the error message that's displayed?

Comment: Thanks for you reply, here is the error:  Server Error in '/AIR' Application.

Access to the path '\\amawebdev92vm\TwShared\Air\2015' is denied.

Comment: So, does your app have access to that path?

Comment: just like what I described, my app can access it from server 2008 iis, and in server 2012, if I open app with http://localhost/app it works, if I open with http://server2012/app it failed.